# How to update service reference in test project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have an existing .net solution which has both wcf project and test project. When I hit F5 , my wcf project starts and hosts the service in iis express. Now I want to update the reference in my test project so that I can test newly added operationcontract. However Visual Studio does not give me that option. Please note both project are part of same solution.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to stop debugging before updating service references?

Comment: yes it works thanks ! I mean after stop debugging. Then I have another query: If debugging is stopped then how come referencing works? Are the information stored in browser or local iis express ?

Comment: I believe the IIS Express keeps running after you stop debugging and you can access your web-service normally (at least it was the case with good ol' Cassini sever a.k.a. ASP.NET Development Server). Alternatively, if for some reason the web-server is not running, Visual Studio should start it automatically before updating service references.